# Javascript Unicode Redex matching NOT a letter or a number

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, unicode, xregexp

I would like to convert this:

```js
var result = mystring.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, ' ');
```

to a functioning unicode version so that I can index ONLY letters and numbers. I don't want [-_%<>...] for example.  Since JS does not support this natively, I am using [xregexp](http://xregexp.com/).

This does not seem to give me any results... Do I have the letter and number part correct here?

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/xregexp/xregexp-all.js"></script>
<script>
    var s = `joanthan------______++++++ <me> bornss $%^&\` asdfasdf+++áeé´sé´s , н, п, р, с, т, ф, х, ц, ч`;
    var r1 = XRegExp.replace(s, /[^\p{L}\p{N}]+/g, ' ');
    var r2 = s.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, ' ');
    console.log(r1);
    console.log(r2);
</script>
```

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't your extended regex by in quotes?

Comment: No, it does not matter, I still do not get different results with ```'/[^\p{L}\p{N}]+/g'``` Quotes are not required, as you can see the regular regex works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their [documentation](http://xregexp.com/api/) `replace` supports two match parameters; `string` and `Regexp`. That being said it will not parse a string expression, and so would be treated as a literal string replacement. To Use a `xregex` you would first have to create a expression instance and then use that as an argument.

```js
var s = `joanthan------______++++++ <me> bornss $%^&\` asdfasdf+++áeé´sé´s , н, п, р, с, т, ф, х, ц, ч`;
var match = XRegExp('[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]+', 'g');
var r1 = XRegExp.replace(s, match, ' ');
var r2 = s.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, ' ');

console.log(r1);
console.log(r2);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/xregexp/xregexp-all.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Unicode property escapes with RegExp (and by extension, XRegExp), you need to set the Unicode flag.

```js
const s = `joanthan------______++++++ <me> bornss $%^&\` asdfasdf+++áeé´sé´s , н, п, р, с, т, ф, х, ц, ч`;
let r1 = s.replace(/[^\p{L}\p{N}]+/gu, ' ')
console.log(r1);
```

Comment: While the other answer is technically what I asked, this is much better as I don't need to import anything.  Thanks!